# what's the matter about appfuse,please

Tags: java, maven, appfuse

when run the command:mvn jetty:run in the web directory,it's the error message:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.mycompany:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.015s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 05 23:31:23 CST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.myco
mpany:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not
be reattempted until the update interval of appfuse-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: ask sonatype about this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have appfuse multi-module web project and you are building the `web` module without having built/installed the `core` module.

Quoting the instruction from appfuse [quickstart](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart), highlighting relevant portion in **bold**.

> To view your application run mvn jetty:run from your project's
>   directory (for a modular project, you'll need to run mvn jetty:run
>   from your project's web directory (**after installing the core module**)).

Comment: hi,Raghuram,I have run mvn install from the core directory before running the mvn jetty:run from the web directory

Comment: @Lu. Can you check if core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar exists in com\mycompany\core\1.0-SNAPSHOT folder in your local repository (M2_REPO)?  Perhaps it did not get installed.  You could try deleting "com\mycompany" folder in your M2_REPO and trying again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `mvn install` from the `project's root directory` also!

Comment: Thank pal, this works! 
I wonder why it was not mentioned in the documentation???You saved me countless hours and grievance!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you definitely need to `mvn install` from your core directory. If this does not help, then run the same command from root directory. The problem is that one of Your modules needs to be installed and only after that the error you are encountering will be removed.